# NumberUtils throws Exception when convert a BigDecimal to Long but sucess when convert to Integer

Tags: java, spring

```
System.out.println(org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(new BigDecimal("18446744073709551611"), Integer.class));
System.out.println(org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(new BigDecimal("18446744073709551611"), Long.class));
```

first line returns -5 but second line throws exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not convert number [18446744073709551611] of type [java.math.BigDecimal] to target class [java.lang.Long]: overflow`

Is that the expect result of method `org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass`?

Comment: and
        System.out.println(NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(new BigDecimal("184467440737"), Long.class));
        System.out.println(NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(new BigDecimal("184467440737"), Integer.class)); first line success and second line throw exception which meet our expectation.

Comment: Spring already fixed it. https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring.

The bounds checking for the conversion to long is correct. It first converts the BigDecimal to a BigInteger and then checks if it is within range of a Long.

```
88      else if (targetClass.equals(Long.class)) {
89          BigInteger bigInt = null;
90          if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
91              bigInt = (BigInteger) number;
92          }
93          else if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
94              bigInt = ((BigDecimal) number).toBigInteger();
95          }
96          // Effectively analogous to JDK 8's BigInteger.longValueExact()
97          if (bigInt != null && (bigInt.compareTo(LONG_MIN) < 0 || bigInt.compareTo(LONG_MAX) > 0)) {
98              raiseOverflowException(number, targetClass);
99          }
100         return (T) new Long(number.longValue());
101     }
```

However the conversion to Integer (and other primitive numeric types) is broken.
It first takes the `longValue` if the BigDecimal and *then* checks if this long value is in range of the type. However if it wasn't in range of the long value, then the long value is a truncated number that is meaningless and may seem to be within range of the smaller type, but wasn't really because the top bits were truncated off in the initial conversion to long.

In your example, 18446744073709551611 truncated to a Long yields -5, which is perfectly in range for an Integer - but the original number clearly was not in range of an Integer.

```
81      else if (targetClass.equals(Integer.class)) {
82          long value = number.longValue();
83          if (value < Integer.MIN_VALUE || value > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
84              raiseOverflowException(number, targetClass);
85          }
86          return (T) new Integer(number.intValue());
87      }
```

To implement this correctly, Spring would need to change the conversion to Integer (and to Short and Byte) to work the same way as the conversion to Long: first convert to BigInteger, then check the range, then convert to the correct type (Integer/Byte/Short).

Comment: Thanks for your implementation. To be honest, I first read the code of NumberUtils then prepare the test code. So does the spring need fix this one?

Comment: @andy I'd think so. Although the range checking itself is not documented in the java doc - but it's there in the code, and it's not implemented correctly for Byte/Short/Integer

Comment: @hagrawal this issue fixed which cause throw overflow when convert to Long, but the same issue still exists for converting to Integer/Short/Byte

Answer (score 0):

> Is that the expect result of method

Yes and no.

Yes, this is the expected result when you specify `java.lang.Long` and gets an overflow for Long.

No, in general, because as per method signature `convertNumberToTargetClass(Number number, Class targetClass)` if the `targetClass` is a subclass of `java.lang.Number` then you do not get this exception. In your case, `java.lang.Long` is subclass, so it will not come but you are getting because of overflow.

Below code snippet from `org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass`

```
public static <T extends Number> T convertNumberToTargetClass(Number number, Class<T> targetClass) throws IllegalArgumentException {
......
else if (targetClass.equals(Long.class)) {
            BigInteger bigInt = null;
            if (number instanceof BigInteger) {
                bigInt = (BigInteger) number;
            }
            else if (number instanceof BigDecimal) {
                bigInt = ((BigDecimal) number).toBigInteger();
            }
            // Effectively analogous to JDK 8's BigInteger.longValueExact()
            if (bigInt != null && (bigInt.compareTo(LONG_MIN) < 0 || bigInt.compareTo(LONG_MAX) > 0)) {
                raiseOverflowException(number, targetClass);
            }
            return (T) new Long(number.longValue());
        }
      .......
      }
```

And here is the code snippet for `raiseOverflowException`, place from where you are getting your exception:

```
    private static void  [More ...] raiseOverflowException(Number number, Class<?> targetClass) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not convert number [" + number + "] of type [" +
                number.getClass().getName() + "] to target class [" + targetClass.getName() + "]: overflow");
    }
```

Check out the implementation of `org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.9.RELEASE/org/springframework/util/NumberUtils.java#NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass%28java.lang.Number%2Cjava.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Thanks. And Integer also is subclass of Number. So I think the first line also need throw exception, right?